# SQL Query With Array

Tags: php, mysql

New to PHP. I have a long SQL query, something like:

```
SELECT name, date, bio, image, articles, related FROM Person WHERE id = $id
```

I want to make a query using mysqli in a manner similar to this:

```
$results = $mysqli->query($testQuery);
```

Where $testQuery is MySQL query I wrote above.

Instead of having to type out that list of fields inside of the query text, I'd like to assign the field names to an array or something similar, and then unpack that array within the query text, so I can do something like

```
$testQuery = SELECT {$listOfFields} FROM Person
```

Anyone know how I would achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
$listOfFields = array('name', 'date', 'bio', 'image', 'articles');

$testQuery = "SELECT ".implode(",",$listOfFields)." FROM Person";
```